# How we can fetch reddit share count/score of a url

Tags: php, json, reddit

I am trying to get reddit url's share count/score using php .I have tried

```
http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url=yoururl
```

method .

I got the results when i just open the link in browser. But when I tried this using curl,

```
 $url = 'yoururl';
    $reddit_url = 'http://www.reddit.com/api/info.{format}?url='.$url;
    $format = 'json'; 
    $score = $ups = $downs = 0; 

    $content = get_url(str_replace('{format}',$format,$reddit_url)); 
    if($content) {
        if($format == 'json') {
            $json = json_decode($content,true);
            foreach($json['data']['children'] as $child) { 
                $ups+= (int) $child['data']['ups'];
                $downs+= (int) $child['data']['downs'];
                //$score+= (int) $child['data']['score'];  
            }
            $score = $ups - $downs;
        }
    }

    echo "Ups: $ups<br />"; 
    echo "Downs: $downs<br />"; 
    echo "Score:  $score<br />"; 
        function get_url($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $content;
    }
```

or file_get_contents method,

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($reddit_url),true);
```

then I got the following error message ,

**Request forbidden by administrative rules**

So I use reddit API then I got the score,UP votes,

```
$pageInfo = $reddit->getPageInfo($url);
```

But there we need to use our login credentials and it have only one hour session.

Please advice me the best method for fetching URL's reddit score using php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "by administrative rules" - in other words, use the official API, and don't screenscrape

Comment: You should read [the reddit API rules](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API#rules), which explain why you had a problem, and also give the rest of the API documentation a good read, too.

Comment: Also, link scores are not in any way related to how many shares they've gotten, but are calculated by votes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CURLOPT_USERAGENT to make it work! Following code will work.

```
<?php
function curlRequest($url){
     $curl = curl_init();
     $time = microtime(true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $data = curl_exec($curl);
     curl_close($curl);
     return $data;
}
echo curlRequest('https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url=http://google.com');
?>
```

Comment: I tried to get score from the url as `http://google.com` but I get only 28 scores.
If I get the points from here https://www.reddit.com/buttonlite.js?i=0&url=http://google.com it show me 128 points. Why is it different?

Comment: @vee "https://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url=http://google.com" request will give you the reddit details of latest shares while the buttonlite.js will give you the cumulative score. Since, 'http://google.com' is a common url, it has been shared more no. of times in reddit and hence you couldn't get older shared details on reddit.